# Sorting a lists within a dictionary using list data

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

My problem is I am trying to sort this lists within a dictionary where I am using the dictionary name as the field name and the lists as the data rows.  I have a feeling I am using the wrong approach (should this be a tuple or a dataframe or what?)

I have tried using `sorted()` but can't get past only sorting by the key (e.g. `name`, `score1`, `score2`).  I want to maintain the key order but rearrange the values while keeping their relationship across keys.

This is a sample dataset that I want to sort by `score1` (or `score2`):

```
scores = {'name': ['joe', 'pete', 'betsy', 'susan', 'pat'], 'score1': [99, 90, 84, 65, 100], 'score2': [85, 91, 90, 55, 98]}
```

After sorting for `score1`, I would like to see:

```
pat, joe, pete, betsy, susan
```

After sorting for `score1`, I would like to see:

```
pat, pete, betsy, joe, susan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create `scores` yourself, it will be much easier if it is structured differently, ie `[{'name': 'joe', 'score1': 1, 'score2': 2}, ...]`.

Then the usage of `sorted` is quite simple:

```
scores = [{'name': 'joe', 'score1': 99, 'score2': 85},
          {'name': 'pete', 'score1': 90, 'score2': 91},
          {'name': 'betsy', 'score1': 84, 'score2': 90},
          {'name': 'susan', 'score1': 65, 'score2': 55},
          {'name': 'pat', 'score1': 100, 'score2': 98}]

by_score_1 = [d['name'] for d in sorted(scores, key=lambda d: d['score1'], reverse=True)]
print(by_score_1)
by_score_2 = [d['name'] for d in sorted(scores, key=lambda d: d['score2'], reverse=True)]
print(by_score_2)
```

Outputs:

```
['pat', 'joe', 'pete', 'betsy', 'susan']
['pat', 'pete', 'betsy', 'joe', 'susan']
```

Comment: ...this is more efficient and clearer than what i suggested!

Comment: I can restructure scores, so this looks interesting.  I then need to add new keys as new tests are created.  This seems easily done by: `for item in scores:
   item.update( {'score3': 90})`
But what if I then needed to update individually by student?  How could I update 'Pat' to a new score 3 of 75?

Comment: @DouglasWood That's a very valid argument, for which the data structure I suggested is a bit less efficient. You will need to iterate over the entire list until you find the correct dictionary: `for person_data in scores: if person_data['name'] == 'pat': person_data['score1'] = new_score`

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is nice. You could also turn it into a list of tuples then easily sort it:

```
scores = {
    'name': ['joe', 'pete', 'betsy', 'susan', 'pat'], 
    'score1': [99, 90, 84, 65, 100], 
    'score2': [85, 91, 90, 55, 98]}

t = list(zip(*scores.values()))
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
[('joe', 99, 85), ('pete', 90, 91), ('betsy', 84, 90), ('susan', 65, 55), ('pat', 100, 98)]
```

Then you can sort it:

```
# Sort by score1
print(sorted(t, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True))

# Sort by score2
print(sorted(t, key=lambda x: (x[2]), reverse=True))

# Sort by both scores:
print(sorted(t, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]), reverse=True))
```

Just a different way to attack the same problem. Doing it this way you can easily print the scores of the individuals as well.

Answer (score 1):

this is a possiblity:

```
print(sorted(scores['name'], reverse=True, 
             key=lambda x: scores['score1'][scores['name'].index(x)]))
# ['pat', 'joe', 'pete', 'betsy', 'susan']
print(sorted(scores['name'], reverse=True, 
             key=lambda x: scores['score2'][scores['name'].index(x)]))
# ['pat', 'pete', 'betsy', 'joe', 'susan']
```

Comment: What if I wanted to display the name and the score?  Also, what if I wanted to not just print but update the dictionary to be in sorted order by score1?